# Summernote WYSIWYG doesn't display properly inexternal popup

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, summernote

I know it must be something easy, but I can't figure this out. Summernote works fine if it is in the first `page` element of a JQM document, but if the summernote is in an external popup or on other pages in a multipage web, they summernote initialized but the icons are spaced oddly--see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alsosun/s1a7ysvg/7/)). I have tried comparing the how the css are applied, and it looks like the JQM theme is overwriting the bootstrap css, though I am not sure (adding !important to all the bootstrap and summernote css is not an option--besides it must be a initialization or loading issue). Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score -1):

If you host the JQuery Mobile scripts locally then you could edit/delete the parts that are causing the problem. Or you could use find and replace to add the important tags: Find:`;` Replace:`!important;`